# What is the alternative of lowercase_expanded_terms in Elastic search 8.9?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-dsl

I know that lowercase_expanded_terms is valid in 2.x version and if the same is tried to execute in 8.9v gives `"reason": "[query_string] query does not support [lowercase_expanded_terms]"`.

```
{
  "size": 1000,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "*TEST*",
            "fields": [
              "elastic*"
            ],
            "lowercase_expanded_terms": false // query does not support
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lowercase_expanded_terms` has been [removed around5.0](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/9978).

Instead you should lowercase your tokens at indexing time using a `lowercase` token filter in your field analyzer or normalizer.

As a result you'll be able to search for `*test*` instead of the uppercase version `*TEST*`.

Comment: do you have any code snippets? By the way which is preferred to go with the field analyzer or normalizer once the index got created?

Comment: it depends on the mapping of your `elastic*` fields. Feel free to update your question with that information

Comment: In my case data is indexed in capital and while I search with upper/lower case from UI at java code I am converting it to upper case and finally hitting to index.